# how use https for many custom domain with a record like http

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

i make website and use IIS web server

now site run with this 2 address

http://panel.example.com and

i can set Arecord for use HTTP with many custom domain name like this

panel.customdomain.com => a record => serverip(x.x.x.x)

http://panel.customdomain.com work just fine but  show error this is not valid in browser(Your connection is not private)

is there any way to use many custom domain with HTTPS address ?
i have some reseller and i dont have fixed list for new domains.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. What do you actually ask? What do you mean by "use a record for http but its not possible for https"? Certainly you need certificates for the hostnames you want to be able to reach via https, but I assume you know that. This has nothing to do with ip addresses, certificates are tied to hostnames (you called that "domain name").

Comment: i edit question . i want to know is there any way to have many custom address for https address?  for example https://panel.site1.com , https://panel.sitenumberX.com and more thats all point to 1 perimary addres.

Comment: You need to keep two things apart: 1. it is absolutely no problem to have multiple hostnames served by a single http server and on a single port. You just need to configure the http server to do so. And obviously all DNS resolutions for those host names need to point to the same ip address, via A record or via CNAME record. Independent from that is the ssl certificate required if you want to use https. You either need a separate certificate for each hostname or a multi site or wildcard certificate. The warning you get indicates that your certificates do _not_ match the hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

If you have full control of your server you can use Let's Encrypt to get ssl certificate for every domain 
OR you can use cloudflare.com and get a free certificate 
Hope it helps